Can a retail investor enter into a reverse repo transaction?
Assuming an investor holds $1M worth of treasuries and urgently needs liquidity, can a retail investor enter into a reverse repo agreement through their broker with any of the institutions in an open market?
There is, of course, an alternative: borrow against assets in your portfolio or take out a margin loan, but these usually carry a much higher interest rate.

Can? Sure. If they find a counter-party. Generally the amount is too small, probably, and a margin account/collateral loan would probably be the way to go.
Repo transactions are short term by definition, and are essentially low risk loans at fixed interest rate. A retail investor who's in the situation you're describing is not a low risk by any measure.
